# now transform showing in maltego for facebook

Tags: facebook

I want to extract email or phone number of a facebook id from facebook. But there is no know transform showing in facebook affilate membership

[facebook transform image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBll5.png)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBll5.png): [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBll5.png)

Comment: There is no way to do that. Where did you get the Facebook Ids from?

Comment: You can use the Graph API to get email, but only for users who have authorized your app. Phone numbers aren't available at all.